# How to initialise a let text attribute

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a text attribute for a foreground colour which I want to use in attributed strings. The attribute is a `let` constant in my class and I want to initialise it with a `UIColor` which I pass into the `init` for the class.

```
class LocationOptions {
    let live : NSAttributedString.Key!
    let black = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    let grey = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray]
    let findingLocation: NSAttributedString!
    let centralLondon: NSAttributedString!
    let allLondon: NSAttributedString!


init(color: UIColor){
        live = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color]
        findingLocation = NSAttributedString(string: "Finding Location...", attributes: grey)
        centralLondon = NSAttributedString(string: "Central London", attributes: black)
        allLondon = NSAttributedString(string: "All London", attributes: black)
    }
    ....
```

With this code the compiler comes up with the error when I assign `live`:

*Cannot assign value of type '[NSAttributedString.Key : UIColor]' to type 'NSAttributedString.Key'*

If I change the declaration of `live` to

```
let live: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor!
```

The compiler comes up with the error when I declare `live`:

*Static let 'foregroundColor' is not a member type of 'NSAttributedString.Key'*

How do I initialise a text attribute like this?

Comment: `live` is defined as a `NSAttributedString.Key` object and you try to set it as a Dictionary which keys are `NSAttributedString.Key` and values `UIColor` (or `Any`). Of course it won't work. It should be `let live : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]!` or `let live : [NSAttributedString.Key: UIColor]!` at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because it needs attribute dictionary.

```
//This is only key and you cannot assign a attribute to it 
let live = NSAttributedString.Key! 

//this is only value
let live: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor!
```

`These won't work`. The way you would make them work is as follow:

```
class LocationOptions {
    let live: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

    init(color: UIColor) {
        live = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color]
    }
}
```

Comment: That works thank you. I was missing the idea that it's a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here…

```
let live : NSAttributedString.Key!
```

`live` is type `NSAttributedString.Key!`, but you're assigning a Dictionary to it.

If `live` is a colour use:

```
let live : UIColor
```

if it's a dictionary of Attributes, use:

```
let live : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `live` as

```
let live: [NSAttributedString.Key : UIColor]!
```

`NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor!` cannot be the type for `live` because it is not a type, it is a property. By declaring `live` as `[NSAttributedString.Key : UIColor]`, you can assign the dictionary to it while being able to initialize the `NSAttributedString` in a simpler way.